# RegEx : Remove line breaks if lookbehind shows a lowercase

Tags: regex, ms-word, ms-office

I'm doing a CTRL+H (Find & Replace) in Notepad++

I want to find all Line breaks followed by lowercase characters in order to replace them with a space character ; thereby removing unwanted break lines in my text.

Find : **\r\n+(?![A-Z]|[0-9])**

Replace : *insert space character here*

*Make sure you selected "*Match case*" and "*Regular expression*".

It works perfect.

Now, I'd like to do the same in Microsoft Office Word documents. Any clues?

Comment: Well, Word documents are not plaintext and linebreaks are more than just `\r\n`...

Comment: Indeed, in Word I used ^13 instead of \r\n successfully. But I'm stuck with the conditionnal lookbehind part.

Comment: I would imagine Office products use an arcane regex engine. Might not have those complicated constructs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Microsoft Word, do the following:

1. On the Home tab, in the Editing group, click Replace to open the Find and Replace dialog box.
2. Check the `Use wildcards` check box. If you don't see the Use wildcards check box, click More, and then select the check box.
3. In the `Find what:` box, enter the following regular expression: `([a-z])^13`
4. In the `Replace with:` box, enter: `\1` - thats: (backslash 1 SPACE) (don't forget the space!)

And that's it!  Then click either the `Replace` button or the `Replace All` button.

Note: In MS Word, the `^13` character matches the paragraph mark at the end of each line.

Here's more information about Microsoft Word and Regular Expressions - http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/find-and-replace-text-by-using-regular-expressions-advanced-HA102350661.aspx

**Edit:**

Oh, the above matches lowercase letter PRECEDING line break.

If you want to match line break FOLLOWED by lowercase letter, do the following:

1. In the `Find what:` box, enter the following regular expression: `^13([a-z])`
2. In the `Replace with:` box, enter: `\1` - thats: (SPACE backslash 1) (don't forget the space!)

Tested both ways and they both work in Microsoft Word 2010, however documentation says that regular expressions are supported in all versions 97 - 2013.

Good luck!  :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help MElliott. I used your edited solution successfully in Microsoft Word 2003.

Answer (score 0):

in vscode tap on find press the keys ctrl/enter for second line then type (?=[a-z]) and in the replace add a space

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).